# Como passar um número em notação científica em Java?

Tags: java

Estou utilizando um método para não exibir notação científica

```
DecimalFormat dfor = new DecimalFormat("#");
dfor.setMaximumFractionDigits(10);  
txtTexto.setText(df.format(valorDouble));
```

Porém quando pressionar um botão ele passa para notação científica.

Comment: Aquilo funcionou como você queria? pergunto isso porque fiquei em dúvida se o que respondi de fato responde o que você perguntou.

Comment: @Qmechanic73 nada verdade eu quero exibir em notação científica, pois para exibir em sem notação científica  já tenho comando que esta na pergunta.

Comment: Ah sim, desculpe-me então, é algo [**assim**](http://ideone.com/SwLMAo) que você quer fazer?

Comment: @Qmechanic73 e algo assim

Comment: Como você queria fazer exatamente?

Comment: @Qmechanic73 vou fazer um pergunta, se achar melhor abro outra pergunta, como que que faço para ler 10 casas exemplo 10000000000 ai aplicar a notação científica que você passou no link.

Comment: Não sou um *expert* em Java mas, acho que [**isso deve servir**](http://ideone.com/b16jsD). O `L` no final é necessário quando for um valor muito alto.

Comment: valeu mas vou abrir essa pergunta pois quero para numero pequeno também.

Comment: Eu ajeitei um pouco a resposta, se tiver algo a mais que eu possa colocar, avise. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Talvez a função [`BigDecimal#toPlainString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toPlainString()) possa servir para esse propósito.

> **toPlainString**: Retorna a representação da *string* deste BigDecimal sem um campo de expoente. Para valores com uma escala positivo, o número de dígitos para a direita do ponto decimal é utilizado para indicar escala.

Veja um exemplo:

```
    Double valorDouble = 7.89894691515E12;
    String valorStr =  new BigDecimal(valorDouble).toPlainString();
    System.out.println(valorStr); // 7898946915150
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://ideone.com/M5NLtn)</kbd>

**Atualização**: Compreendi errado a pergunta, o código acima faz o contrário do que foi perguntado, ele converte um número com formato científico para *string*.

Para passar um número para notação científica, por exemplo [*10000000000*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/53704/como-passar-um-n%C3%BAmero-em-nota%C3%A7%C3%A3o-cient%C3%ADfica-em-java#comment110148_53704), pode ser feito assim:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0E0");    // Formato

Double valorDouble =  10000000000.0;
System.out.println(df.format(valorDouble));     // 1E10
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://ideone.com/YiOowC)</kbd>

Para passar um número com cinco casas decimais para notação científica, faça assim:

```
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.0000E0");

    Double valorDouble =  12345.0;
    System.out.println(df.format(valorDouble)); // 1.2345E4
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://ideone.com/rjn4QW)</kbd>

Se o formato utilizado for nulo, uma exceção `NullPointerException` será lançada, se for inválido, `IllegalArgumentException` é lançada.

No *link* abaixo explica como criar e personalizar formatos, embora esteja em inglês, é bastante compreensível e contém exemplos.

- [Personalizando Formatos](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html)

Answer (score 2):

Outra forma de apresentar um número em notação científica é usando o `System.out.printf()`:

```
double number = 0.123456;
System.out.printf("%5.2E", number); //saída: +1,23E-01
```

Note que no exemplo acima, a saída exibe:

- o expoente com duas casas;
- o sinal do expoente;
- o sinal da mantissa.

Para mudar a quantidade de caracteres após a vírgula, basta mudar o "**format**".
Exemplo de **format**: "%3.2E" ou "%5.4e"

Exibindo a saída com 4 caracteres apóes a vírgula

```
double number = 0.123456;
System.out.printf("%5.4E", number); //saída: +1,2346E-01
```

Para exibir a letra, que representa a base, minúscula ou maiúscula, basta alterar o **format** da seguinte maneira:

```
double number = 0.123456;
System.out.printf("%5.2e", number); //saída: +1,23e-01
```

Observe que a letra que antecede o expoente está minúscula, como no **format**.

Caso você queira exibir "ponto" ao invés de "vírgula", adicione o `Locale.ROOT` antes do **format**:

```
double number = 0.123456;
System.out.printf(Locale.ROOT, "%5.2e", number); //saída: +1.23e-01
```

Comment: Ao contrário do comentário acima, não vi grandes problemas na resposta (a não ser a falta de formatação, que já foi corrigida). Só um detalhe, `printf` usa o *locale default* que está configurado na JVM, então nem sempre ele usará vírgula: caso o *default* seja um *locale* que usa o ponto e vc quer a vírgula, por exemplo, teria que usar um `Locale` específico em vez do `ROOT`. Veja aqui um exemplo: https://ideone.com/dxt4bw - por fim, se em vez de imprimir, vc quiser gerar uma string contendo o número formatado, pode usar `String.format` (com os mesmos parâmetros de `printf`)